# Charting components in IOS

Tags: ios

My requirement is to do a time-frequency plot somewhat similar to the native IOS audio player app. I am totally unfamiliar with charting components in IOS. Could someone kindly suggest a starting point

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/waveform-audio-player). There's also a detailed example of waveform rendering using OpenGL [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch2/Introduction/Intro.html).